# "von dem" oder "wovon"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, relative-clause

> Das ist alles, wovon ich träume.

soll richtig sein. Da habe ich eine Frage: Kann "von dem" "wovon" in dem Satz ersetzen?

> Das ist alles, von dem ich träume.

klingt ja irgendwie komisch. Ich glaube, dass das keiner sagt, aber ich kann nicht genau begründen, ob oder wie das falsch ist.

Da stelle ich mir die zweite Frage: Wie unterscheiden sich Relativadverbien und Relativpronomen mit Präposition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In diesem Fall ist es besser „wovon“ zu verwenden. Der Grund ist – und das ist gleichzeitig eine generelle Tendenz –, dass das, worauf sich das Relativpronomen bezieht, kein klar definiertes Objekt ist.
„Alles“ wird erst durch den Relativsatz gefüllt, vorher kann es wortwörtlich alles sein. Ein anderes Beispiel sind Sätze, wo gar kein Objekt vorhanden ist.

> Das ist, wovon ich geträumt habe.

Hier kannst du „von dem“ gar nicht verwenden, da das „dem“ etwas Konkretes braucht, auf das es zeigen kann. Das genau braucht ein wo-Pronomen nicht.
Je „wohletablierter“ die Referenz, desto besser kann man auf das wo-Pronomen verzichten.

> Das ist, wovon ich geträumt habe. … *nur „wovon“*
>   Das ist etwas, wovon/von dem ich geträumt habe … *beide, „wovon“ meiner Meinung nach besser*
>   Das ist das Haus, von dem ich geträumt habe … *„wovon“ klingt hier merkwürdig*

Für eine genauere Betrachtung mit mehr Beispielen siehe [diesen Artikel](https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/wo-compounds-worauf-woraus-wovon-meaning-german/) auf meinem Blog (in Englisch)

Comment: Ich würde so weit gehen, "das Haus, wovon" als falsch zu bezeichnen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz "das Haus, wovon" ist nicht per se falsch, da das "wovon" sich ja nicht zwingend auf "das Haus" beziehen muss; aber im Bezug auf die Problemstellung hier, würde ich deine These durchaus unterstützen.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are possible and correct.

Comment: The first version is clearly higher register, though.

Comment: And some dialect speakers will struggle with the first version...

Answer (score 0):

1 Der Mann, von dem ich das weiß, war sehr alt und hat die Sache selbst erlebt.

2 Du weißt nicht, wovon du redest.

Aus dem Stegreif würde ich sagen,

- von dem, bei Bezug auf ein Maskulinum (Person /Sache)
- von der, bei Bezug aud ein Femininum (Person/Sache)
- von denen, bei Bezug auf Plural (Personen/Sachen)
- wovon, bei Bezug auf allgemeines "das" - Das, wovon ich erzählen will hat sich in meiner Jugend ereignet.

Aber Deutsch kann so kompliziert sein, das ich mich bei diesem Problem erst bei Duden oder anderen Quellen genauer informieren müßte. Das gleiche gilt für  Relativadverbien. Aus dem Handgelenk heraus würde ich sagen, der/die/das und welcher/e/es können als Relativpronomen fungieren, wo und ähnliche unveränderliche Wörter als Relativadverbien.